# How to make ImageSharp.Web to resize images from a local directory other then wwwroot

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, imagesharp

I'm developing a Blazor server application and I'm trying to implement imagesharp.web (V.3.01)

I have to use a folder called "Uploads" (not inside wwwroot). I'm trying to use PhysicalFileSystemProviderOptions, setting the ProviderRootPath to the desired folder, but it is not working.

Can anyone help on this problem?

```
var pathToUploads = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads");
var pathToUploadsCache = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads", "is-cache");

builder.Services.AddImageSharp(options =>
    {
        options.BrowserMaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        options.CacheMaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);

    }).ClearProviders()
    .AddProvider<WebRootImageProvider>()
    .Configure<PhysicalFileSystemCacheOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CacheRootPath = null;
        options.CacheFolder = pathToUploadsCache;
        options.CacheFolderDepth = 8;
    })
            .SetCache<PhysicalFileSystemCache>()
    .AddProvider<PhysicalFileSystemProvider>()
    .Configure<PhysicalFileSystemProviderOptions>(options=>
    {
        options.ProviderRootPath = pathToUploads;
        }); 

var app = builder.Build();



// Set Uploads folder
SD.ContentRootPath = app.Environment.ContentRootPath;
SD.UploadsFullServerPath = Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, configuration["UploadsFolder:Name"]);
SD.UploadsRequestPath = configuration["UploadsFolder:WebPath"];
SD.UploadsNameOnly = configuration["UploadsFolder:Name"];
SD.UploadsRootFolderName = configuration["UploadsFolder:RootFolderName"];
SD.UploadsRootFolderWebPath = configuration["UploadsFolder:RootFolderWebPath"];
app.UseImageSharp();

app.UseStaticFiles();

if (!Directory.Exists(SD.UploadsFullServerPath)
    || !Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(SD.UploadsFullServerPath, SD.UploadsRootFolderName)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(SD.UploadsFullServerPath, SD.UploadsRootFolderName));
}
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, SD.UploadsNameOnly)),
    RequestPath = SD.UploadsRequestPath
});
```

Comment: Is it Blazor webassembly or server?

Comment: it is a blazor server

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? In my case setting the ProviderRootPath property of the PhysicalFileSystemProviderOptions class is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Right after AddImageSharp define this method:

```
services.AddImageSharpCore(
            options =>
            {
                options.MaxBrowserCacheDays = 7;
                options.MaxCacheDays = 365;
                options.CachedNameLength = 8;
                options.OnParseCommands = _ => { };
                options.OnBeforeSave = _ => { };
                options.OnProcessed = _ => { };
                options.OnPrepareResponse = _ => { };
            })
```

Add UseWebRoot in your Program.cs class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseWebRoot("myroot") // name it whatever you want
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this guy here: **[create-your-own-image.html](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2022/03/imagesharpwebcreate-your-own-image.html)** solve this, in the ImageSharp documentation, its possible to see two types of Image Providers, that's not what we need, but in the top of the page has this note: **It is possible to configure your own image provider by implementing and registering your own version of the IImageProvider interface.**

read the documentation [IImageProvider](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp.Web/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Providers.IImageProvider.html).

Comment: Do not ask for follow up in an answer. The code you have here is enough to ask a proper Question.

Comment: True, I'm going to publish a complete question, it will be more effective in finding a solution to my problem